# ASCII checking if input contains Letter or number not working?

Tags: java

I'm writing this simple program, and on the data validation part, where the program must reject the users input if it contain contains a number, by using ASCII, but by using `(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))` doesn't seem to work[image]

[image]

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Liu_YiJun_A2Q4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fName = "", lName = "", type = "", add = "", post = "", use = "c", use2 = "";
    int age = 0, phone = 0, numOfU = 0;
    char ch = 0;

    while (use.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
        System.out.println(numOfU);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter your FIRST name:   ");
        fName = input.nextLine();
        while (fName.length() >= 15 && (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')){
            System.out.println("The characters in the name are too long OR The value is not a letter");
            System.out.print("Please enter your FIRST name:   ");
            fName = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("Please enter your LAST name:    ");
        lName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter your AGE:          ");
        age = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please either FT ot PT:         ");
        type = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the ADDRESS:       ");
        add = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the POSTAL CODE:   ");
        post = input.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter your PHONE NUMBER: ");
        phone = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("*********************************************");

        String val = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 9000) + 1000);
        System.out.println("Membership ID: " + val);
        System.out.println("Name of new member: " + fName + " " + lName);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age);
        System.out.println("User is: " + type);
        System.out.println("Address: " + add + " " + post);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
        System.out.println("Member Since: " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter (C) to enter a new user or X to Exit: ");
        use = input.next();

        if (use.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for using ICMSG Membership System. You have entered " + numOfU + " users in this session. Have a nice day!");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: as you can see from the screenshot intelliJ is highlighting something on the `if` condition. hover over it and see what it tells you. this either means your condition is wrong and is always _false_ (which i believe it's) or it's always true or that intelliJ is suggesting you could shorten the condition. nevertheless the condition is always false.

Comment: note that your never assign anything other than 0 to `ch`.

Comment: What other should I assign? @luk2302

Comment: @Aominè could you give me a suggestion of how to fix that condition?

Comment: For future understanding: [`Character.isLetter(ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-),  [`Character.isDigit(ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-),  [`Character.UncodeBlock.of(ch)==Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#BASIC_LATIN)

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer directly because of learning purposes, but here's how you should do that:

```
 final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyz"; // define allowed chars
 char inputChar = 'c'; // get the input from scanner or whatever
 boolean allowed = alphabet.toUpperCase().contains(Character.toUpperCase(inputChar) + "");
```

Then you'll know, if the given char is an alphabet letter.
As @VGR pointed in comments, it's not a task for Regex.

Also, put the `alphabet` variable as a class member to prevent constant memory allocation in loops.

Answer (score 0):

You checked that the character `ch` is an ASCII letter.
However you must check that every character from the input is a letter.
After the input is read.

To do that you need to loop through all chars from the string `fName` and so on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fName.length(); ++i) {
    char ch = fName.charAt(i);
    if (is not a letter) {
        break; // Error, jump out of the for-loop.
    }
}
```

For `fName` and all other inputs.

If the for-loop is still not treated, use a while-loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < fName.length()) {
    ...
    ++i;
}
```